# Returning to lists in tuple format while applying functions to both

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to create a function that takes in a list, applies a function giving a boolean and separates the list into two lists creating one tuple.

So for example if I had the expression separate `odd [1,2,3,4,5]`. I would get the output `([1,3,5],[2,4])`.

My code this far is:

```
separate:: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
separate func []        = ([], [])
separate func [x]       = if(func x == True) then ([x], []) else ([], [x])
separate func (x:xs)    = if(func x == True) then (x : (fork func xs), []) else ([], x : (fork func xs))
```

The first two parts for empty and single lists work as expected, but the real bulk of the function does not work out. I'm not really sure how to perform the expression recursively while at the same time building two distinct lists.

I've tried playing with the built in filter and map functions as well but have had no real success. If anyone has suggestions on how this could be accomplished, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hoogle to find a function knowing it's signature.

[`hoogle (a->Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3EBool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%28%5Ba%5D%2C+%5Ba%5D%29) returns [`partition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3apartition) as one of the answers:

```
Prelude Data.List> partition odd [1,2,3,4,5]
([1,3,5],[2,4])
```

Comment: Its [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#partition), accessible from Hackage, may be enlightening as well.

Comment: Great resource! Thank you so much, I had no idea Hoogle existed!